# SQL Query counter column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I need to query to produce a results set like this:

```
ColA   ColB   ColC
====   ====   ====
AA     BC     1
AA     BD     2
BB     DD     1
BB     EE     2
BB     FF     3
CC     AA     1
```

(There are more rows than this 'fictional' sample)

Only ColA + ColB exist on the table, ColC needs to be generated by the query, Each different 'ColA' needs to reset the count back to 1 in ColC, but then count upwards until the next value in ColA.

I'm using MS/SQL2008.

Thank you - I have tried to search to see if others have asked similar questions, and have seen queries which make use of:

```
row_number() over (order by ColA, ColB)
```

but as I understand it, that will just give me a sequenced list from 1..6 as per this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to partition your row numbering - each partition has it's own set of 1, 2, 3, ... row numbers.

```
row_number() over (partition by ColA order by ColB)
```

Comment: Thank you - that's perfect WillA

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ColA,
    ColB,
    row_number() over (partition by ColA order by ColB) as ColC
FROM
    Test
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c704/2)

You can add `ORDER BY ColA`, to force order you'd like to achieve (but demo shows it's not necessary).

Comment: Thank you @MarcinJuraszek, helpful example.   I accepted Will's as my accepted answer, because he got there first - but again, thankyou for taking time to answer too.